# Acceder a método de un componente desde otro

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estoy en Angular y necesito invocar a un método de un componente desde otro.

Teniendo este componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popover',
  templateUrl: './popover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss']
})
export class PopoverComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
  @Input() texto:string;


  toggleWithGreeting(popover, texto: string) {
    if (popover.isOpen()) {
      popover.close();
    } else {
      popover.open({texto});
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

Necesito alcanzar el método toggleWithGreeting desde el componente padre, tengo esto:

```
send(){
    this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.popName.nativeElement).toggleWithGreeting("","");
}
```

Pero no funciona, no soy capaz de acceder al método, el html por si puede ayudar es este:

```
 <app-popover #popName [texto]="'Esto va a ser el mensaje de error'" ></app-popover>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder desde el padre al hijo a todos sus componentes necesitas usar @ViewChield()...

> Componente padre app-padre

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-padre',
templateUrl: './padre.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./padre.component.scss']
})
export class padreComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChield(PopoverComponent, {static:true}) popoverComponent: PopoverComponent;

 constructor() {}
 ngOnInit(): void {}
 send(){
  this.popoverComponent.toggleWithGreeting("" , "");
 }
}
```

> Componente hijo app-popover

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-popover',
templateUrl: './popover.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss']
})
export class PopoverComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}
@Input() texto:string;


toggleWithGreeting(popover, texto: string) {
 if (popover.isOpen()) {
  popover.close();
 } else {
  popover.open({texto});
 }
}

ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```